# Magento Category - add picture

Tags: image, magento, block, catalog

I've got magento template. I have tried adding a custom block to the RHS of the Catalog, eg:
Catalog
|-Applications
          - Applications List 1 Column,  Apps2 column, Custom Block

I can create App columns and list under all sub menus, but when i'm trying to add Custom Block (pic in this case), to right or left then the Picture shifts the Apps columns :/
See the screenshots.
thank you!

http://s6.postimg.org/5grafpoip/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use code given in following link.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/how-to-get-category-thumbnails-in-navbar-menus

It uses observer to add category thumbnail in navigation menu.

Comment: This should be a comment.